# How to interact with a dialog window in chrome headless with UIVeri5

Tags: javascript, protractor, sapui5, uiveri5

I'm writing tests in UIVeri5 for my Bachelor's Thesis and have encountered a problem with Chrome headless browser. I started with the normal headed Chrome where I could just focus on the dialog popover and press a button which is on there, but for some reason in headless mode, the button is not found.

I expect that the "Back" Button is pressed, then the dialog pops up with the text "do you want to cancel?" and the buttons "yes" and "no". Then the "no" button should be pressed.

I already tried including autowait: true in my code and a chained matcher.

```
it("should click on the back button and go back to creating", function() {
    element(by.control({
      controlType: "sap.m.Button",
      properties: {
        type: "Back"
      }
    })).click();

    element(by.control({
      controlType: "sap.m.Dialog",
      interaction: "focus"
    })).element(by.control({
      controlType: "sap.m.Button",
      autoWait: true,
      properties: {
        text: "No"
      }
    })).click();

    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual(x.afterHashtag(browser, "#/NewProductInfo"));
  });
```

I expect that after the "Back" Button is pressed, the dialog pops up and it searches for buttons on the dialog.

Instead the console log displays that the dialog is found on the page and returned, then all buttons are found on the **page**, not in the dialog window.

Comment: If I understand you correctly the above code works if you are running a head-full chrome instance, right? This only doesn't work on headless? If this is the case it almost sounds like a bug in UIVeri5.

Comment: @SebastianLimbach Thank you for your comment! That's correct, everythings runs fine in headful chrome, but it does not in headless. I also suppose it's a bug in UIVeri5, I will open an issue on github.

Comment: @2Can First step to debug such issues is to look at the screenshots in the screenshot report. Do you see the button you want to click ?.

Comment: @2Can, autoWaiter is always enabled, actually there is no way to disable it in uiveri5 and that's by design. So this part autoWait:true doesn't have any influence. Actually very soon unsupported values in control selector object will throw an error.

Comment: @Max Thank you for your comment! Just to clarify, I wrote the tests in German and therefore referred to the text on the button as "Nein", which means no. When I reviewed the screenshots, I realized that headless chrome automatically translates to English, which headful chrome does not. My problem is therefore solved if I build my tests in English. Thank you again for the tip with the screenshots, it helped a lot!